# Are we meant to work 9 hours a day - everyday?

Tags: hours

I love programming and computer networks, and I find it very interesting.

I also love playing PC games - but I rarely play 9 hours a day.

I also love many other things, that I would seldom do for 9 hours a day.

Why is that in our culture that we have to work every day for so many hours?

I sometimes feel like I'm starting to dislike what I do for a living.

Comment: There is nobody here who can answer this question for you.

Comment: reddit.com/r/antiwork

Comment: Simple answer? Nope.

Comment: This question made me laugh.  But technically we are very lucky, most humans worked every daylight hour and slept the rest just to be able to eat.  Getting away with only 9 hours and having time to play games is crazy luxury to people even 120 years ago.

Comment: @Trevor, yes but during winter they were laying around and doing nothing...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you only have to work a specified amount of hours if you are *employed* by *someone else*. You can find an employer that employes you for less hours per day. Obviously, they will pay you less, too. If you decide to be self-employed or have your own company, you can set whatever hours you are comfortable with and pay you any salary you can afford.

That said, 9 hours every day sounds like you work in some kind of sweatshop. In western countries, we are used to 8 hours days on 5 days a week.

Answer (score 1):

This question assumes a steady state society and uniform capabilities among humans.

When society and your lives are at risk, humans have worked insane hours to prevent loss of life.

I've seen some studies suggesting that hunter gatherer societies have 4-6 hours of work each day and other studies suggesting more of an 8-hour day work.

More importantly, you need to discover for yourself what makes you the most productive and work in that manner. Each person is different, and circumstances are different which means that everybody has a different answer for this. You may find that your answer changes in different situations.